# How to make a Faq page like this in Asp.net

Tags: datagrid

I would like to make a **FAQ** page similar to here: [Forum FAQ](http://forum.deeptechtons.net/faq.php)
using an sql database. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: No nope, i couldn't get a better thing to show my requirements. Sorry it made you think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the final answer for my own question. Here it is it

```
  <asp:Repeater id="faqCategoryList" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <h4>
                            Frequently Asked Questions</h4>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='#<%# Eval("FAQCategoryCode")%>' class="lnkButton">
                            <%# Eval("CategoryName")%>
                        </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <SeparatorTemplate>
                        <hr class="dashed" />
                    </SeparatorTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                        </div>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <fieldset id='<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["FAQCategoryCode"]%>'>
                            <legend><span style="font-size: medium; font-weight: bold;">
                                <%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["CategoryName"]%>
                            </span></b> </legend>
                            <asp:Repeater id="Repeater2" datasource='<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem).CreateChildView("FaqRelation")%>'
                                runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
                                        <%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Question"]%>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Answer"]%>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <SeparatorTemplate>
                                    <hr class="dashed" />
                                </SeparatorTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)" style="float: right">
                                        <img src="Images/png/icon_back_top.gif" class="lnkButton" alt="top" />Top</a>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </fieldset>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <br />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

create table faq_questions and add there questions,

table structure:

categorie, question, answer

and the read that data to website, what programming language you are using?

Comment: As the question goes, it is Asp.net. And Yes i do have the table setup and all. But i would like to implement the functionality where the questions & Answers are listed with a Category Title.[bcoz the Standard Data Controls do not allow to databind in the Header Template] also the problem would be solved if Number of repeaters used = No of faq category but isn't that a untidy thing to do. How could i accomplish this with a simple repeater controls or what ever you think might me possible

Comment: I think i am getting somewhere near by here is a rough psedocode,ForEach(Category){PrintCategoryName,List all the question and answers in the category}. Now atleast  could someone tell me how to achieve this